# Visual Studio 2022 Custom Project Template doesn't show after unzipping / zipping

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have created a new Project Template by exporting a project via Project -> Export Template. Opening Visual Studio now, I can see my template showing up.

I then went to

```
Documents\Visual Studio 2022\My Exported Templates
```

and moved the MyTemplate.zip to another folder. Went to

```
Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates
```

and made sure that MyTemplate.zip is not in there as well.

Now when I open VS again, I can see that my template is not available anymore.

To counter check, I moved the zip back into *Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates* , reopened VS and made sure that the template is visible again.

I then went ahead, extracted MyTemplate.zip and compressed it into a zip again (Right Click -> Compress to Zip). Now when I move that zip into *Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates* and restart VS, the template does **not** show up.

Bottom line, I am unable to import any template that I have manually compressed into a zip archive, seems like *something* is happening to the zip during extract / compress. I have been testing this on Win 11 with the OOB zip tools as well as nanazip.

Comment: When manually creating a .zip, it's easy to accidentally have the files put inside a folder inside the .zip. If you double-click the .zip, are the files shown in the root of the .zip or inside a folder? For single project templates, the files in the root of the .zip.

Comment: @Gen1-1 this was the issue with me. thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try extracting your template project ZIP file?
I was struggling as well but as soon as I extracted my custom template project with the rest of the Default templates it started showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [this comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/custom-project-templates-not-showing-in-create-new/1289638#T-N1453631) and to my surprise, the culprit was with OneDrive.

The standard location of templates is this one:

> {user}\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates

However in my case, VisualStudio was looking for templates under OneDrive in a this directory:

> {user}\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates

As a general tip - since it seems that VisualStudio might look for templates in different locations - while exporting a template using the wizard, check the option to automatically import it. Then try to search/locate the template name. In my case, I was able to identify that it was under OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

VS template is looking for folders in the `..\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates\` not a zip file. If you want your template to show up, move its folder there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I named the XML file `.vstemplate`. It needs to be `something.vstemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to start VS2022 as administrator, the templates are shown.
Had also tried it again as normal user and adjusted the permissions of the zip and folder for all users, but it still was not displayed. Had also changed the location, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, you need to compress files to zip exactly in ..\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates.

I you do it in another place and copy zip file to the ..\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates\ you can not see this template in VS.